# Timeout Sql Server em uma requisição via Web Api

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Ao executar a query obtenho um erro de TimeOut Sql Server:

**Método da Conexão:**

```
public SqlDataReader GetDataReader(string comando)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = criaConexao();

            // Cria Comando
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comando, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter oP in alParameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(oP.ParameterName, oP.Value);
            }


            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                return reader;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                //conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Método que popula o modelo:**

```
public List<MeuModelo> SelectProduto(MeuModelo meuModel)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                DataAcess dataAcces = new DataAcess();
                List<MeuModelo> lModel = new List<MeuModelo>();

                sb.Append(" SELECT ");
                sb.Append("  prd.ProductID, prd.ProductName, cat.Nome");
                sb.Append(" FROM");                
                sb.Append("     Products as prd (NOLOCK)");
                sb.Append("         INNER JOIN Categoria as cat (NOLOCK)");
                sb.Append("             ON prd.ProductID = cat.ProductID");
                sb.Append("         WHERE prd.ProductID = 1");

                SqlDataReader dr = dataAcces.GetDataReader(sb.ToString());

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        MeuModelo meuModelo = new MeuModelo();
                        meuModelo.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"]);
                        meuModelo.Nome = dr["Nome"];
                        lModel.Add(meuModelo);
                    }
                }

                return lModel ;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro na query que seleciona produto categoria: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

A query quando executada no sql server management studio é muito rápida e retorna 1 registro apenas. 
Essa query é usada por uma web api e após umas 3 chamadas é retornado TimeOut do Sql Server: `"Erro na query que seleciona produto categoria"`.

Como resolver esse problema de Timeout considerando que a execução da query é rápida e simples ?

Comment: Você precisa fechar a conexão, o problema está aí, retornando o DataReader para a outra camada da sua aplicação. Porque você não popula a lista e retorna ela para o seu SelectProduto ?

Answer (score 1):

Observando o seu código não encontrei onde você fecha a conexão após a execução, rapidamente você pode resolver colocando um con.Close() no Finally, verfique se dessa forma resolve seu problema.

Recomendo alterar seu código para:

```
con = getConexaoBD();
try
{
    con.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT prd.ProductID, prd.ProductName, cat.Nome" +
                 " FROM Products as prd" +
                 " INNER JOIN Categoria as cat" +
                 " ON prd.ProductID = cat.ProductID" +
                 " WHERE prd.ProductID = 1";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int32, "ProductID"));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value = ProductID;

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        modelo.ProductID = rdr["ProductID"]
    }

    return .....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return throw new Exception("Erro na query que seleciona produto categoria" + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Existe uma outra forma de escrever o seu código, utilizando o **using** recomendo utilizar dessa forma, um código de exemplo: (*exemplo retirado do SOEN*)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["Person"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("No C-Level with Head Up Ass Found!? (Very Odd)");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message); }
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
    }
}
```

***Retirado do site da Microsoft:***
Quando o tempo de vida de um objeto IDisposable é limitado a um único método, você deve declará-lo e instanciá-lo na instrução using. A instrução using chama o método Dispose no objeto da forma correta e (quando você o usa como mostrado anteriormente) ele também faz com que o objeto em si saia do escopo assim que Dispose é chamado. Dentro do bloco using, o objeto é somente leitura e não pode ser modificado ou reatribuído.
A instrução using garante que Dispose seja chamado, mesmo que ocorra uma exceção dentro do bloco using. Você pode obter o mesmo resultado colocando o objeto dentro de um bloco try e então chamando Dispose em um bloco finally. Na verdade, é dessa forma que a instrução using é convertida pelo compilador. O exemplo de código anterior se expande para o seguinte código em tempo de compilação

Caso queira obter mais informações sobre o using:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: Olá @Thiago Loureiro eu não posso fechar a conexão pois eu tenho que retornar o `SqlDataReader` para uma outra instância, percebi que o exemplo que coloquei não está completo e vou alterar o código do post para ficar mais claro, ok ?

Comment: Você esta mantendo a conexão sempre aberta então? Não parece correto, voce deve abrir conexão , extrair os dados, fechar a conexão e retornar.

Comment: Tem razão, vou fazer o seguinte ao invés de usar SqldataReader usarei um DataTable e depois posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Isso, faça tudo lá na sua camada de dados, preencha o que você precisa, fecha a conexão e retorna o objeto (seja datatable, lista). mas não esqueça de fechar a conexão :)

Answer (score 0):

Como foi observado nos comentários pelo [Thiago Loureiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/90970/thiago-loureiro) troquei o `SqlDataReader` pelo `DataTable` e funcionou.